# Editing closed or off topic questions

Tags: discussion, editing

I have made a few edits to questions that were closed or off topic, I always ask the OP if they are happy with the edit, and only offer it, after it's received a bit of attention and there seems to be no editing, or if I know the OP and we discuss help with editing.

[Does a dog's pink or white skin need special care?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/575/is-the-skin-of-lighter-coat-dogs-more-sensitive)

[Why should I not give water or food to a wounded bird?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/140/why-should-i-not-give-water-or-food-to-a-wounded-bird)

[What is causing behaviour changes in our young adult dog?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/264/what-is-causing-behaviour-changes-in-our-young-adult-dog)

- How does the community feel about this type of editing?
- In these early stages, it is a small group we are trying to get our site organised; but how should we proceed with this as the site grows?

Comment: Whether or not you think you can interpret the OPs intent or not, it is important to remember that you aren't the OP, so drastic edits need to still be avoided.

Comment: So... Should I re-write the question? I didn't understand the changes so that's why I didn't want to interfere. How can I fix this?

Comment: @LucyGalván does the question, as it is currently worded adequately ask your question? Or is it different from what you intended to ask?

Comment: It seems they are talking about a specific dog but it seems that it doesn't change what I intended to ask in the first place.

Comment: @LucyGalván I didn't think you were discussing a specific dog, but asking a general question about skin type. If you are happy with the edit, then there is nothing for you to worry about. It's only if I had edited it to change what you were trying to ask.

Comment: @LucyGalván if you are unhappy with the current wording, you can click the `edit` button below the question (or [here](http://pets.stackexchange.com/posts/575/edit)). It is quite common that questions are edited by members of the community to improve their quality. However if you are unhappy with an edit you are free to roll back any changes made. You can do that by clicking on the link "edited Oct 12 at 16:22" which will bring you to the revision history of the post. There you can chose a revision and click rollback. If you need more help you can always drop by in [chat].

Answer (score 6):

One thing to avoid is to change the intent of the question completely. Edits that are too radical or change the fundamental intent of the question should not be acceptable - some questions are just not repairable, and sometimes we have to ask new questions or risk completely changing the OP's question, which is something we don't want to do.

Sometimes, we can't fix a question and being it off of the on hold status. That is alright - we can't save everything. 
Making some attempt to correct a question to make it fit is alright, but changing the question or adding details that only the OP would be able to confirm or know about is not a very good idea - the point of editing is to make adjustments, not to change things completely.

It is entirely possible a question will be on hold for a day or more or perhaps forever (especially if it is considered off topic).  While it is not ideal, it is just the way it goes - we can't make everything work, as much as we would like to.

We are attempting to create a good solid base of awesome questions, and editing is part of that! But we also don't want to change the intent of the question or make it completely unrecognizable from what the OP was actually trying to ask (unless it is poorly written, etc).

This is one of those cases where we don't want to treat edits now any different than the edits we do later when the site is in public beta. We want good edits that improve questions, not change them or make assumptions about things that we really have no way of knowing.

Comment: Coming across off-topic questions also helps people realise what's not on topic.